# Using BDC to connect and extract list data from another web application?

Tags: bdc, connection

Can BDC on SharePoint 2010 be used to connect to another SharePoint 2010 web application?

Comment: Yes, this could be done via a custom .NET connector. But there might be other ways to achieve your goals if you could add a bit more detail to your question.

Comment: Hi Robert, I have a farm with several web applications and I currently have the need to publish list data from one WebApp into all the anothers. I've been able to do this with a DVWP, however the information is comming from a Calendar List and using the DVWP I am unable to expand reoccuring events. Only the first instance of the reoccuring event is shown. So I'm looking into other ways to make this work. I don't have much experience at building custom Visual Studio solutions and wanted to try and keep this as out-of-the-box as possible.